# How do I connect a Gcloud Virtual Machine to Colab using a local connection?

Tags: python, ssh, google-colaboratory, gcloud

I am trying to combine gcloud VMs and Google Colab using the local runtime connection.

`gcloud compute ssh [Instance] --zone [ZONE] -- -L 8080:localhost:8080 -N -T`

Connection is established but the runtime appears as "busy" on colab. I am pretty sure that nothing is running on the VM.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Please check out this guide (last section) - [Connecting to a runtime on a Google Compute Engine instance](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can mount GDrive and access files from both sides.